# How to know cron job is written right?

Tags: ubuntu

I have started cron job for taking backup after every five minutes but the output is not showing. Does this mean my cron tab file is wrong or service is not started ?
I cron job successfully run then what massege is shown in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu look in `/var/log/syslog` which is where (by default) cron logs it's activity.

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

If you modify your script to output a message on success/failure etc. then cron will mail the output to the account that is running the job e.g. root. You can modify this behaviour by adding a [**`MAILTO=you@your.tld`**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/) directive in the **[crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)** file.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting crontab problems can be *very* frustrating. I've spent days troubleshooting some tricky script that ran fine manually but failed each time they were executed via crontab.

The other tips are very good. The only thing I can add is that you should make sure that your crontab session has access to all of the necessary environment variables. For example, just because '/usr/local/foobar/bin' is part of your PATH variable, it doesn't mean that your script will know than when it's executed via crontab. You may therefore want to use full paths as much as possible in your script, or "source" a properties files when the script begins so that you know that the proper variables are set.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to see if the cron daemon is running:

`ps -e | grep cron`

Also, have a look in

`/var/log/cron`

to see if there are any entries.

Answer (score 0):

cron mostly doesn't display a message unless you put that into the job script

The only way is to either look in the logs (/var/log/cron)

Or (since this is a backup script) just add a file in the folder that will be backed up, and then check if the file is indeed backed up

Answer (score 0):

I generally just redirect the output to a log file of some kind:

```
30 * * * * cmd > /home/user/log/cmd.log
```